# Pseudocode for BMI

Tags: pseudocode

I was asked to design a pseudocode that calculates and displays a person's body mass index (BMI) based upon their weight and height.

I would like to know if I'm headed in the right direction or if I'm completely off.

This is what I have so far:

```py
Start
  DECLARE NUMBER height, weight, bmi

  DISPLAY "Enter person's information:"
  DISPLAY "height in inches? "
  INPUT height

  DISPLAY "weight in pounds? "
  INPUT weight

  height = height * 0.0254    # convert inches to meters
  weight = weight * 0.453592  # convert pounds to kilograms
  bmi = weight / (height * height)

  IF bmi < 18.5
    DISPLAY "underweight"
  ELSE IF bmi >= 18.5 AND bmi < 25
    DISPLAY "normal"
  ELSE IF bmi >= 25 AND bmi < 30
    DISPLAY "overweight"
  ELSE
    DISPLAY "obese"
  END IF
END
```

Comment: You can omit the `bmi >= 18.5` because you would catch those with the previous if. Same for the `bmi >= 25`.

Comment: What is the last `END` for?

Comment: Always found bmi calculations are incorrect - at 6’ 3” and some 17 stone its results label me incorrectly. So will your version give correct results?

Comment: @SolarMike what do you consider correct? Your BMI is 29.76.

Comment: A [BBMI](https://tall.life/better-bmi-for-short-and-tall-people/) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Because if you have a lot of muscle it assumes it is fat… and yes I have discussed this with medical professionals as I have 4 in the family.

Comment: @ValerijDobler the last end refers to the end of the program (start-end)

Answer (score 1):

The pseudocode is correct, but it performs unnecessary comparisons.

For instance, when the first condition is false, you know by consequence that `bmi >= 18.5`. There is no need to verify this in the next `IF` clause.

So that `IF..ELSE IF..` construct can be simplified to:

```py
  IF bmi < 18.5
    DISPLAY "underweight"
  ELSE IF bmi < 25
    DISPLAY "normal"
  ELSE IF bmi < 30
    DISPLAY "overweight"
  ELSE
    DISPLAY "obese"
  END IF
```